# How to get Google search results page into a DOMDocument object in PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, curl

I'm not looking to scrape Google. This just a one-time thing to get about 300 urls a bit faster than manually doing it.

I can't seem to get a DOMDocument to be created though. It always ends up as an empty object.

`search_list.txt` contains my list of search terms. Right now I'm testing it with just 1 term, "legos".

The script correctly downloads the search results page. I viewed it in a web browser and it looked fine.

search_list.txt

```
legos
```

getresults.php

```
<?php
$search_list = 'search_list.txt'; // file containing search terms
$results = 'results.txt';

$handle = fopen($vendor_list,'r');

while($line = fgets($handle)) {
        $fp = fopen($results,'w');
        $ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/'
        . 'search?q=' . urlencode($line));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FILE,$fp);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
        unset($ch,$fp);
}
fclose($handle);


$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML(file_get_contents($results));
echo print_r($dom,true); // EMPTY
$search_div = $dom->getElementById('search');

if(is_null($search_div)) { // ALWAYS NULL
        echo 'Search_div is null';
} else {
        echo print_r($search_div,true);
}

?>
```

Comment: can you post at least partial results.txt (all would be better) ? Browser will successfully deal with javascript and render page correctly but DOMDocument will not, just want to see if that is the case.

Comment: With all that code, what exactly does not work? Is there an error message? Can you reduce the example please? Isn't it possible to reproduce with test-data totally unrelated to google? etc. pp.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes.

Instead of `fopen` - `fgets` - * ,  `file` .

Instead of `curl`,  `simple_html_dom::load_file`

```
$search_list = 'search_list.txt'; // file containing search terms
$result_list = 'results.txt'; // file containing search terms

$searching_list = file($search_list);
foreach ($search_list as $key => $searching_word) {
    $html->load_file('http://www.google.com/'.'search?q='.urlencode($searching_word));
    $search_div = $html->find("div[id='search']");
    echo $search_div[0]; // See content of the search div.
    file_put_contents($result_list,$search_div[0]);
}

?>
```

You can see the results with `echo $search_div[0];`.

It shows you whole content of search div .

**I searched for 'asd' =) ...**

Based on my results , it is started with like

```
<div id="search"><div id="ires"><ol><li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrial_septal_defect&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=5qhMUv36ILKX0AXxuYGYCQ&amp;ved=0CBgQFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFo67q2pfiPWK5SDMKFTeu-QSfcxw"><b>Atrial septal defect</b> - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px"><cite>en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<b>Atrial_septal_defect</b></cite><span class="flc"> - <a href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:Ocu9slAHjr4J:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrial_septal_defect%252Basd%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=5qhMUv36ILKX0AXxuYGYCQ&amp;ved=0CBkQIDAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEY245u_ERgmZd7-2vIk5RAIRbOeg">Cached</a> - <a href="/search?ie=UTF-8&amp;q=related:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrial_septal_defect+asd&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=5qhMUv36ILKX0AXxuYGYCQ&amp;ved=0CBoQHzAA">Similar</a></span></div><span class="st"><b>Atrial septal defect</b> (<b>ASD</b>)
```

And ended like

```
</span><br></div></li><li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://achievementschooldistrict.org/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=5qhMUv36ILKX0AXxuYGYCQ&amp;ved=0CEQQFjAJ&amp;usg=AFQjCNHqINq_rlt8mbk2WmlATfpx-fyP8w"><b>Achievement School District</b></a></h3><div class="s"><div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px"><cite>achievementschooldistrict.org/</cite><span class="flc"> - <a href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:s8DoGxDbr4oJ:http://achievementschooldistrict.org/%252Basd%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=5qhMUv36ILKX0AXxuYGYCQ&amp;ved=0CEUQIDAJ&amp;usg=AFQjCNEPhVqK33c7ruuXT7cwVe3-8JdUVA">Cached</a></span></div><span class="st"><b>Achievement School District</b> &middot; The <b>ASD</b> &middot; Driving Results &middot; Campuses &middot; Join Our <br>  Team &middot; Enroll A Student &middot; <b>ASD</b> News &middot; Contact Us&nbsp;<b>...</b></span><br></div></li></ol></div></div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

This part is based on comment of **Buttle Butk** .

If there is no change the first 1st result of google search you can use this code to get the first result in the search.

```
<?php
$search_list = 'search_list.txt'; // file containing search terms
$result_list = 'results.txt'; // file containing search terms
$order_language = "en"
$searching_list = file($search_list);

foreach ($search_list as $key => $searching_word) {
    $link = 'https://www.google.com.tr/search?hl='.$order_language.'&q='.$searching_word.'&btnI=1';
    echo $link;
    file_put_contents($result_list,$link[0]);
}
?>
```

I searched for 'asd' =) again ...

The result

```
https://www.google.com.tr/search?hl=en&q=asd&btnI=1
```

When i copied and paste to chrome , this link redirect to me to 1st result of 'asd searching'.

```
http://www.asd-europe.org/
```

If i can help you , i'll feel happy . 
Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks for your improvements. Actually, I'm trying to get the 1st result link from the search results. Any way to get the `a href` inside the first result div?

Comment: it's smells 'I'm Feeling Lucky' =). I'll prepare another answer for you